# Как проигрывать реверсом медиа файлы в Visual Basic(Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-basic

Столкнулся с проблемой при создании медиа проигрывателя. Мне нужно добавить возможность проигрывать видео или музыку задом наперёд(а не просто отматывать назад) с помощью трёх разных скоростей, и после этого ещё сохранять записанный задом наперёд файл. Буду признателен любой помощи.

Правка - всё ещё не нашёл способа сделать это. Использую в основе проигрыватель Windows, если это как то поможет вам дать совет.

Comment: Реверс байтового потока? не подойдет?

Comment: @Dmitry, вероятно, не подойдёт.

Comment: @Dmitry Поискал информацию,не думаю, что это подойдёт в моём случае(